# How to save fonts in fonts folder after reboot windows ce 6.0

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-ce

I have a handheld device on Windows CE 6.0 operation system, I'm trying to add one additional font for web application and when I put it in \windows\fonts folder everything works but when I reboot device font disappears and font folder becomes empty. Please help me to save this font in this folder or help me to find a specific folder where I can put this font and it will work.

Comment: You may try to add more details to your question, like what font etc. That will help people to suggest answers.

Comment: It is not about specific font file. after reboot any  file of .TTF format which I put in this folder disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following things are in check.

1. Your login account should have write access to the C:\Windows\Fonts
   folder, this point you have done.
2. The registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts should be fully modifiable by your account
3. Make sure the font files are not encrypted. If you need advice how to not encrypted the font please see [here](https://www.fonts.com/support/faq/fonts-disappear-on-restart)

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ I have access only til this path and after this there is only Drivers32 folder